# How do you securely provide a sensitive info (e.g. password) to a background application to be started?

Tags: java, security

I am working on a Java application that should be run in the background and was thinking of externalizing some sensitive info (DB credentials among others) in case it should change. These info is required in order for the application to start. However, I was wondering what is the proper way of doing this?

I was thinking of the following but needs advice from a security standpoint.

1. Encrypted passwords will be passed as Main arguments when starting the application. However, I noticed that any user can see the arguments when the list of processes in the OS will be viewed.
2. Generate an external file, i.e. java properties file (with encrypted credentials) with view restrictions, and pass the file path to the application
3. Put the encrypted credentials in the user's environment variables for the application to access it

Note: We already have an encryption tool that we use

Personally, I was leaning to the 2nd option but I would like to know suggestions, comments, or best practices for cases like this.

Thanks!

Comment: [ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) and [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) for encrypting anything you need encrypted.

Comment: Hi, we already have an encryption tool that we use, will edit the post to include this info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 is the most sensible option. Problem with 1 and 3 is, once they have access to the "encrypted" string, all they have to figure out how are you decrypting it (You anyway have to do it, to make use of it).

Have you looked at [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/), I don't know whether this is an option for your or not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked Spring Cloud Config but it seems way too overkill to use it for our simple application. (I'm using plain java)

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is most common. 
Personally, I do not recommend Option 1 and 3.

There could be other options too.

As example you can look at PicketBox Vault.
It allows to make custom implementation more secured than default.

In fact it is extended option 2 - there is a Vault file protected by key stored in Keystore.

Still password to that Keystore(alias) must be secured,  but only one(two). It is useful, when there are many properties need to be secured. It is also more manageable, since all properties secured same way and in one place.